# R: Shiny ggplot renders upside down online, but not offline

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I made a small Shiny app that visualizes some simple data in a set of barplots. One of the charts is a barplot showing time intervals plotted against the date. This renders exactly as expected when running the app offline in R, but when I publish it to shinyapps.io, the bars are oddly inverted and run from the top of the plot down towards the x-axis. Examples:

Offline
[image: Offline (running in R)]

Online
[image: Online (running on shinyapps.io)]

I have a set of similar barplots not based on time-data that seem to work fine both published and unpublished. The app is entangled in reactive elements, so I'm not sure how to provide a minimal reproducible example, but on the server side, the plot is rendered using:

```
output$dayplot <- renderPlot({
p <- ggplot(myplotdata(), aes(day, var, fill=State, color=State)) +
                geom_bar(stat="identity") +
                xlab("Day") +
                ylab(input$yvar) +
                scale_x_continuous(breaks=pretty_breaks(10)) +
                scale_y_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("1 hour"),
                                 labels = date_format("%H:%M")) +
                coord_cartesian(ylim = c(as.POSIXct("0:0:0", tz = "GMT", format="%H:%M:%S"),
                                         as.POSIXct("12:00:00", tz = "GMT", format="%H:%M:%S"))) +
                scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired", type="qual") +
                scale_color_brewer(palette="Paired", type="qual")
print(p)
})
```

I've read through my code multiple times, but cannot comprehend how this phenomenon could arise online while working fine offline, so I'm not entirely sure what to be looking for. This is also my first Shiny app, so any ideas and input as to what might have caused this is very welcome!

Edit:
I've since gone through all of my code, reducing it to the bare minimums. While I couldn't pinpoint exactly what triggered the problem with complete certainity, it seems to have been related to my time variable taking on the sys.date time when formatted as POSIXct. This worked fine in the preview, but not on the shiny server. However, manually setting this date to 1970-01-01 by pasting it onto the character time-variable before converting to POSIX seems to have resolved the issue on my end. So if other future readers come upon a similarly funky problem, perhaps this suggestion can be of some help.

Comment: Can you add an example dataset as well as the code for the reactive function `myplotdata`?

Comment: I seem to have gotten it to work in the mean time, though I'm not confident what exactly solved it. I think the root of the problem may have been the formatting of the time variable (see edit in the OP).